# QGIS expression builder include relation attributes

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql, symbology

I have a set of symbols based on a table in postgis such as this

```
id|type|action_1|action_2|geom
```

In QGIS I have this table symbolised using a rule expression which works effectively.

However this table was setup as a bit of a rush job, as it doesn't adhere to 3NF structure and is inflexible (i.e. what if more than 2 actions needed). As such the structure is now:

Table 1

```
id|type
```

Table 2

```
id|tbl_1_id|action
```

Where I have a 1-n relationship between table 1 and table 2. I have incorporated the forms and entering data works perfect. However I am trying to incorporate the same rule based symbology as I had previously.

I have tried using the  reffuntion plugin, which doesn't do this (or I haven't been using correctly). I have tried creating a view in my database and joining it to table one so I have a field which I can then symbolise on. However when I edit the data, the view table does update - however the joined table does not update - even after pressing the refresh data button.

Any thoughts on how to symbolise based on two tables OR refreshing data in joined tables would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF you have a view in PostGIS, you could use that as the table that you edit, so long as you only edit attributes from the master table. You could concatenate the action fields (from the one-to-many relationships) so that you have unique combination of actions to symbolize on.

My point is, visualising from a view out of postgis will ensure that it's always up to date in QGIS. You can either edit on the underlying table, or on the view, so long as you are careful with what you edit on the view.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Alex for the answer; I also found that the reason my view was not updating was simply to me loading it with the cache table option checked. Un-checking this fixed it.

Comment: Ok, so unchecking the 'cache' option within QGIS made the join dynamic?

Comment: Yeh, sorry I should be more specific - when you join the view to the dataset in QGIS and have the 'Cache join layer in virtual memory' option unchecked the join will now be dynamic.